# Update SSBO in Compute shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, compute-shader

I am currently trying to update a SSBO linked/bound to a Computeshader. Doing it this way, I only write the first 32byte into the `out_picture`, because i only `memcpy` that many (`sizeof(pstruct)`).

Computeshader:

```
#version 440 core

struct Pstruct{
  float picture[1920*1080*3];
  float factor;
};

layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer Result{
  float out_picture[];
};
layout(std430, binding = 1) buffer In_p1{
  Pstruct in_p1;
};
layout(local_size_x = 1000) in;

void main() {

    out_picture[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x] = out_picture[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x]  +
                                           in_p1.picture[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x] * in_p1.factor;

}
```

GLSL:

```
struct Pstruct{
   std::vector<float> picture;
   float factor;
};

Pstruct tmp;
tmp.factor = 1.0f;
for(int i = 0; i < getNUM_PIX(); i++){
   tmp.picture.push_back(5.0f);
}

SSBO ssbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &ssbo.handle);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, ssbo.handle);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, (getNUM_PIX() + 1) * sizeof(float), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

...

glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo.handle);
Pstruct* ptr = (Pstruct *) glMapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
memcpy(ptr, &pstruct, sizeof(pstruct));
glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);

...

glUseProgram(program);
glDispatchCompute(getNUM_PIX() / getWORK_GROUP_SIZE(), 1, 1);
glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);
```

How can I copy both my `picture array` and my `float factor` at the same time?
Do I have to split the `memcpy` call into array and float? and if yes how? I can copy the first part, but I am not allowed to add an offset to the `ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

> ```
> float picture[1920*1080*3];
> ```

clearly should be either a texture (you're only reading from it anyway) or at least an image.

Second:

> ```
> struct Pstruct{
>    std::vector<float> picture;
>    float factor;
> };
> ```

This definition does not match the definition in your shader in any way. The `std::vector` object will just be a meta object internally managing the data storage used by the vector. `memcpy` that to a GL buffer and passing that to the GPU does not make sense at all.

The correct approach would be to either copy the *contents* of that vector separately into the appropriate places inside the buffer, or to just us a struct definition on your client side which actually matches the one you're using in the shader (and taking all the rules of `std430` into account). But, as my first point already was, the correct solution here is most likely to use a texture or image object instead.

Comment: wouldn't making it into an image2d reduce the numeric accuracy? image2D takes RBGA8 maximum? otherwise that would be absolutely the right call, didn't think of it.

Comment: No, you can have full 32 bit float per channel texture and images, see `GL_RGBA32F` format.